# How to calculate instantaneous frequency of the wav file

Tags: python, wav, frequency-analysis, audio-analysis

I have a wav file containing the recording of the human voice. I want to calculate the average frequency of the words spoken. Normally the male voices are upto 200hz and female voices are slightly higher. For eg. I want my answer like 170 hz like that and I cannot figure out the way to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Did you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458214/split-speech-audio-file-on-words-in-python ?

Comment: You need to use SciPy to read/analyze the wave file and calculate the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) sample in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377665/python-scipy-fft-wav-files

Comment: I don't have to split the audio, i just want the frequency of the voice.